# Java generics: syntax clarification needed

Tags: java, generics

Suppose i have a

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and would like to have this list reversed with the help of

```
public static List<Object> reverseList(List<Object> o);
```

Thought process here is that one day i may be dealing with Integers and another with Doubles. Would be nice to have a generic method that is able to reverse my Lists

How should reverseList be declared for this to work? Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to declare it is

```
public static <T> List<T> reverseList(List<T> o) {
  ...
}
```

You might also want to take a look at [`Collections.reverse`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: Your first example does not work - you will lose the type information.  The second is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
public static <T extends Number> List<T> reverseList(List<T> o) {
```

Comment: +1 for including a bound on the generic parameter - this seems like it might be relevant based on the question, and even if not it gives the syntax for later adaptation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> in);
```